# Display image from image collection One Bye one in Some Time Interval

Tags: asp.net

I have a Array of Image Name By which I Display Image on The page,But I want to Display Image like Slide show in div.  in Some Time Interval,   Will You Please Guide the best way to do this !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use jquery cycle for making image sliding.

**Nivo slider** and **coin slider** are the best example....

You should visit this link.. and you get to know that .. what you should do?

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Jquery Slider Pluging URL : Best plugin you should choose and use as fulfill your requirement

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/

Comment: Give me comment, if it helps you.

Comment: At Your Side You Are true to Use Jquery Slider,Thanks For Listen Me,,

Comment: How To accept the Ans. ?     By click on Yes/No Or By Other Type

Comment: click on yes sign under the up and down arrow in my answer.

Comment: you should also accepted you previous question's answer, so, your accepted answer ratio raise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Update Panel and Timer.
Check out this tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/dmiyamasu/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-ajax-slideshow-using-updatepanel-and-timer.aspx

Hope This helps.